# Error in contrasts: group by factor and the minus operator in `formula()` stops working

Tags: r, dplyr, formula, lm

The error occurs when using `group_by()` on a factor, even though this factor is afterwards [removed from the model using the minus operator (`-`)](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.5.2/topics/formula). My motivating example:

```
library(tidyverse)
df = mtcars %>% mutate(am = factor(am))
fits = df %>%
  group_by(am) %>%
  do(fit = lm(formula(mpg ~ . - am), .)) # Returns the error
```

Which gives the following error message:

> Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) :   contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels

I get the same error, if I `filter()` instead of group:

```
fit_am0 = df %>% 
  filter(am == 0) %>%
  lm(formula(mpg ~ . - am), .) # Returns the error
```

It is as if the `formula()` function does not properly detect the minus operator (`- am`) when the variable I try to remove is a factor, i.e. the combination of the two. This is my guess, since the following examples work without error:

```
fits = mtcars %>% # `am` is numeric
  group_by(am) %>%
  do(fit = lm(formula(mpg ~ . - am), .)) # No error
```

```
fit_am0 = df %>%
  filter(am == 0) %>%
  select(-am) %>% # `am` removed prior to running model
  lm(formula(mpg ~ .), .) # No error
```

```
fits2 = mtcars %>% 
  mutate(vs = factor(vs)) %>% # A non-grouped factor, later removed
  group_by(am) %>%
  do(fit = lm(formula(mpg ~ . - vs), .)) # No error
```

Is this a bug? Or did I make an error in my motivating example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Remove the factor in the data option instead of in the formula option, i.e. `lm(formula = formula(mpg ~ .), data = select(., -am))`.

```
library(tidyverse)
df = mtcars %>% mutate(am = factor(am))
fits = df %>%
  group_by(am) %>%
  do(fit = lm(
    formula(mpg ~ .), 
    select(., -am)
  )) # No error
```